# Are there any APIs for Cardano NFT ticker?

Tags: nft, api

I am very new to Cardano NFT. I am trying to find an API to get the Cardano NFT live ticker.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi @Surabhiv, could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean exactly? I am not sure what you mean by "NFT live ticker". I think it might be better to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, @LACEpool thank you for your reply. Actually we need API to get Cardano's current price, current Marketcap, Volume, Supply,7 days price for graphical representation.

Answer (score 2):

> Actually we need API to get Cardano's current price, current Marketcap, Volume, Supply,7 days price for graphical representation.

this kind of information is not directly related to Cardano in the sense that it is not on-chain data. I'd suggest you check out different providers and choose what fits you best. I haven't used any of the following, but a quick search in Google resulted in the following list:

- https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Endpoint-Overview
- https://www.coingecko.com/en/api
- https://www.coinapi.io/
- https://docs.coincap.io/
- https://polygon.io/crypto

This is just an excerpt of my search for "crypto market api" and "blockchain market api" and you can find many other providers.